# win10 does not support the field whose type is geography

Tags: sql-server, windows-10, geography

this is a programm which was executed in windows 10 with dotnetframework4.6.1

```
public void GetData()
{
  string sConnectionString; 
        sConnectionString = @"Data Source=www.somedomain.com;Initial Catalog=iislog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=iislog;Password=password";

        SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString);
        Conn.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        DataSet ds;
        ds = new DataSet();

        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select top 10 name From geo", Conn);
        adapter.Fill(ds, "name");

        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select top 10 geo From geo", Conn);
        adapter.Fill(ds, "geo");

    }
```

the database engine is ms sqlsever 2008,
geo is a table which contains a field 
whose type is geography,and another field 
whose type is nvarchar(50).

when execute to the statment
adapter.Fill(ds, "geo");
an exception was thrown,

but if i execute the program in windows 7,no error occures.

exception screenshot:

[image]

the table structure:

[image: the table structure]

Comment: And not to make this too easy, you didn't include the details about the exception?

Comment: the exception screenshot was added.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` assembly installed on the Windows 10 box. Support for `SqlGeography` doesn't ship with .net.